# For a closed $n$-cell $D$ and $p\in\operatorname{Int}D$ there is a continuous function $F:D\to[0,1]$ s.t. $F^{-1}(1)=\partial D$ and $F^{-1}(0)=\{p\}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity

Suppose $D$ is a closed $n$-cell, i.e. $D$ is homeomorphic to the closed $n$-Euclidean ball. Given any point $p \in  \operatorname{Int}D$ show that there is a continuous function $F: D \to [0,1]$ such that $F^{-1}(1) = \partial D$ and $F^{-1}(0)=\{p\}$.

I think I need to use the following fact. Given a continuous map $f: \partial D \to \partial D'$, for closed cells $D$ and $D'$, there is a continuous extension $F: D \to D'$ with $F(\operatorname{Int}D) \subset\operatorname{Int} D'$ that sends a given point $p \in\operatorname{Int} D$ to $p' \in  \operatorname{Int} D'$.

I think we should set $D' = [-1,1]$ and $f(x)=1$ for all $x \in \partial D$. Then we should have a continuous extension $F$, such that $F(\operatorname{Int} D) \subset (-1,1)$. So $F^{-1}(1) = \partial D$, but I don't know how to ensure that only $p$ is sent to $0$. Also I cannot ensure that the codomain is $[0,1]$ instead of $[-1,1]$. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you do it explicitly when $D$ *is* a closed ball?

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the fact that $D$ is perfectly normal, as any metric space. If you take any compatible metric $d$ on $D$ we can take

$$ F(x) = \frac{d(x,p)}{d(x,p) + d(x, \partial D)}$$

as an explicit such map.

Answer (score 0):

On taking $D'=[0,1],\ f : \partial D\to \partial D'$ to be the constant function $f(x)=1$, the claim follows from the fact that every continuous map $f : \partial D\to \partial D'$ extends to a continuous map $F:D\to D'$ with $F(\text{IntD})\subseteq \text{Int}D'$.

To prove this, choose homeomorphisms $\phi:\overline {B^n}\to D,\ \psi:\overline {B^m}\to D'$ such that $\phi$ and $\psi$ map boundaries to boundaries, and define $\tilde f:S^{n-1}\to S^{m-1}$ by $\tilde f=\psi^{-1}\circ f\circ \phi$. Then, $F=\psi\circ G\circ \phi^{-1}$ where $G(x)=\|x\|\tilde f(x/\|x\|)$ is the desired extension.